# Nested grouping in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have this data structure

```
data: {mid: bytearray,country_code: bytearray,cnt: long}

4679201,RUS,1
4679201,GB,1
4679201,US,1
4681046,GB,2
4681046,TR,1
4681046,FR,1
```

I need to loop through each 'mid' value and store its corresponding data in a 'csv' file.

```
STORE mid_data INTO '/mypath/4681046';
```

The output file would look like:

```
GB,2
TR,1
FR,1
```

it looks like there's already a function (org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage
) that does that, except I do not want my key (mid) to be part of the output.

Thanks

Sadek

Comment: Can you just `cut` your output when you need it? Is the issue that you don't have enough storage?

Comment: I'd rather keep everything in the Pig script and not have to post process the data if possible.

Comment: Ah, that's totally understandable. One solution would be to implement your own StoreFunc based off of MultiStorage, which would give you a lot of flexibility around what is stored and what is not, but you'd have to weigh the expense of maintaining a custom StoreFunc versus maintaining some post processing.

Answer (score 0):

To store just last 2 columns in the output file use FOREACH.

Ex:

```
view = FOREACH mid_data GENERATE country_code, cnt;
STORE view INTO '/yourpath/3452345';
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. The problem is the path is dynamic. I need to look through all the 'mid' values then store its corresponding data.

Comment: Do you know values upfront or you want to calculate them dynamically?